# Saving Original Data with Data-Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm-light

I have a user control that contains a combo box which gets its values from an enum. I've bound that combo box to an attribute of a model. Whenever I change the selection of the combo box, it also changes the attribute of the model. I want to be able to implement a save command, so that the value selected by the combo box only changes when a save command is use and so that the original data can be preserved if the user wants to cancel the change.

One solution I thought of it having separate attributes or a separate model to contain the data, but it seems to be a hack and very inelegant. How would you solve this problem?

ViewModel

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Margin="8, 0, 0, 0">
    <Label Content="Current Status"/>
    <ComboBox SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedRequest.CurrentStatus}" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={extension:EnumBindingSource {x:Type Requests:RequestStatus}}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Request

```
public class Request 
{
    public RequestStatus CurrentStatus {get; set;}
    .......
}
```

RequestStatus

```
public enum RequestStatus
{
    Created,
    Prepared,
    Delivered
}
```

Comment: If you want to have multiple versions of some given state, and you want to save/revert that state, then you should put it in a class. You'll have two properties: `Request Request` and `Request EditingRequest`. When the user starts editing `Request`, they're actually editing a clone in `EditingRequest`. When they hit Save, `Request` is replaced with a new clone of `EditingRequest`. If they hit Cancel instead, `EditingRequest` is replaced with a new clone of `Request`. That's elegant enough for me. You could also give them an undo/redo stack that way if you're feeling brisk. .

Comment: Maybe `Request` isn't the unit of state you want to save/revert; same principle applies if you do it only with values for the `RequestStatus` enum rather than instances of `Request`.

Comment: I was thinking of doing something like that, but I'm new to mvvm and wpf so I wasn't entirely sure if that's the standard way or the best practice to handle that. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

Solution I settled on was an implementation of the [Momento design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/memento_pattern.htm).

Since creating copies of every single attribute in my model class would be rather ugly, there being 10+ attributes which vary in complexity. The example I linked above uses a CareTaker class, which in the context of my code is represented by a ViewModel class.

RequestMomento

```
public class RequestMomento
{
    public RequestStatus Status {get; set;}

    public RequestMomento(RequestStatus status)
    {
         Status = status;   
    }
}
```

Request

```
public class Request 
{
    public RequestStatus CurrentStatus {get; set;}

    public RequestMomento SaveStateToMomento()
    {
        return new RequestMomento(CurrentStatus);
    }

    public void GetStateFromMomento(RequestMomento momento)
    {
        CurrentStatus = momento.GetStatus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I never knew there was a pattern for that.